# Como convertir de 'string' a 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>',

Tags: c#

Como covertir este linea "listTemp.AddRange(fullPath);" -> de 'string' a 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. debo obtener los PDF de una carpeta para concatenarlos en un documento nuevo en PDF

```
public string[] GetFiles()
        {
            List<string> listTemp = new List<string>();

            string pathBase = @"C:\Users\bodega\Documents\Manifiestos";

            List<string> trasteList = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                                                .Select(row => row.Cells[1].Value.ToString())
                                                .ToList();

            foreach (string traste in trasteList)
            {
                string fileName = string.Format("{0}.pdf", traste);
                string fullPath = Path.Combine(pathBase, fileName);
                // -----------------------------
                listTemp.AddRange(fullPath);
                // -----------------------------
            }

            return listTemp.ToArray();
        }
```

Comment: porque abres una nueva pregunta cuando solo era cuestion de esperar un seg a que cambiara el AddRange() por el Add()

Comment: Muchas Gracias Leandro debo agilizar este proceso porque es parte del trabajo no estaba seguro que me pudiera contestar

Comment: @LeandroTuttini creo que no le mencionaste o Saul no vió que hiciste ese cambio en tu respuesta, de la pregunta que marcaste como duplicada.

Comment: Si es verdad no vi la respuesta hasta este momento, Diculpe la molestia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fullpath` es sólo un `string`, no una colección de ellas (por cada iteración se inicializa un nuevo `fullpath`), así que sólo usa `Add`

```
listTemp.Add(fullPath);
```

Comment: Gracias por la correcion. lo deje asi y funciono ahora me concatena todos los PDF que le paso en la lista

`listTemp.Add(fullPath);`

Comment: ¿en un mismo segmento de tu lista?

Comment: Yo traigo a una DataGrid por medio de una cosulta a la BD y tomo de ese DataGrid los datos que quiero concatenar (PDFs) para luego unirlos en un solo documento y asi imprimirlos por ambas caras para ahorrar de esa forma mucho papel

Comment: quieres guardar todos los path en una misma variable? no entiendo bien cual es el problema

Comment: Ya esta resuelto, debo tener una lista de archivos PDF en una ubicacion que me indica cuales debo concatenar

Comment: No te entendía jajaja, lo siento. mucho éxito hermano :)

Answer (score 1):

El AddRange se utiliza para adicionar colecciones de datos a tu objeto lista,
para añadir un solo valor usa Add:

```
public string[] GetFiles()
    {
        List<string> listTemp = new List<string>();

        string pathBase = @"C:\Users\bodega\Documents\Manifiestos";

        List<string> trasteList = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                                            .Select(row => row.Cells[1].Value.ToString())
                                            .ToList();

        foreach (string traste in trasteList)
        {
            string fileName = string.Format("{0}.pdf", traste);
            string fullPath = Path.Combine(pathBase, fileName);
            // -----------------------------
            listTemp.Add(fullPath);
            // -----------------------------
        }

        return listTemp.ToArray();
    }
```